# How to find which branches are not covered by tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-coverage, coverage.py

I am measuring code coverage of a small Python application.

Although line coverage is 100%, branch coverage is not. The problem is that [`coverage`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage) won't give me any indication about the location of branches not being covered.

```
coverage run
    --branch
    --omit=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/*,tests/*
    -m unittest discover
```

returns:

```
Ran 33 tests in 0.079s

OK
Name              Stmts   Miss Branch BrMiss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------------
app/__init__          1      0      0      0   100%   
app/file_finder      93      0     40      0   100%   
app/zipper           66      0     46      7    94%   
-------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL               160      0     86      7    97%
```

I would expect `Missing` column contain the lines corresponding to seven missed branches, but there is nothing there.

How should I find them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-m` will only include the "full" misses, not the branch misses. You can use the command

```
coverage html
```

to create a set of HTML pages that includes highlighting for all of the coverage, including branch misses. See e.g. [this example](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/sample_html/) of HTML reporting, from [the documentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/).

Answer (score 4):

If you are brave enough to try a pre-release version, coverage.py 4.0 will show missing branches in the textual report also.

Comment: coverage.py 4.0 is working for me for this purpose; when I am on a system with older coverage my workaround is `python -m coverage xml; less coverage.xml`